# Why can't I run apt-get update?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

[image]

I just installed Chrubuntu 14.04 LTS with unity and this is what happens when I try to run apt-get update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. You *did*.

Those messages at the end are just warnings. You can ignore them (without harm or fault) or fix the problem they describe by cleaning out the duplicate lines in your `/etc/apt/` sources files.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue remove every duplicated line in sources.list with GEdit or any text editor as root (with sudo)